# О выделении запятыми слова «думаю» в разговорной речи

Tags: запятые, синтаксис, вводные-слова, разговорная-речь

В разговорной речи часто встречаются моменты по типу: "Сейчас, думаю, что невозможно". Равнозначно: "Сейчас, думаю, невозможно". То есть невозможно что-либо конкретно сейчас.
Нужно ли выделять "думаю" запятыми с обеих сторон?

Comment: "Сейчас думаю, невозможно" тоже возможно.

Answer (score 1):

В первом варианте запятая перед *думаю* не нужна: ***Сейчас думаю, что невозможно***. Вводные слова, как правило, можно опустить из предложения без потери структуры. Здесь же структура нарушится (Нельзя так: ***Сейчас, что невозможно***). Поэтому запятая только с одной стороны.

А в предложении: ***Сейчас, думаю, невозможно*** — пунктуация верна. ***Думаю*** можно изъять без потери структуры (*Сейчас невозможно*). Это вводное слово, которое требует обособления с обеих сторон.

Answer (score 0):

Если после *думаю* стоит *что* – запятая перед *сейчас* не ставится. Этот принцип работает и с *хотя* + *но*, и с *когда* + *то* и т.д. Есть продолжение – значит, запятая только одна.

«Сейчас думаю, что невозможно».

Answer (score 0):

"Думаю" — это форма первого лица (настоящего времени, единственного числа) глагола "думать". Она может выполнять в предложении функцию сказуемого или вводного слова.

• *Сейчас, **думаю,** невозможно.*

В этом предложении "думаю" является вводным словом:
служит для выражения мнения автора;
не является членом предложения и не отвечает на вопросы от других слов;
может быть удалено из предложения без нарушения его структуры и смысла;
имеет синонимы — *полагаю, на мой взгляд, считаю, кажется, наверное, возможно.*

•• *Сейчас **думаю,** что невозможно.*

В этом сложноподчиненном предложении "думаю" является сказуемым (подлежащее "я" пропущено, но подразумевается; запятая ставится только перед союзом "что"):
является главным членом предложения и не может быть удалено без нарушения смысла;
отвечает на вопрос "что делаю?";
может употребляться в значении *считаю, полагаю.*

*Образно объяснял себе своё безделье, но сравнение определило развитие фантазии, — **сейчас думаю, что невозможно** охватить всё...* (А. Еремин. Рассказ).

В отсутствие же союза, считаю, лучше поставить не запятую, а тире — для обозначения увеличенной паузы.
Возможный пример:
*— Да, ты прав... Еще неделю назад я считал, что можно объединить фирмы и получить выгоду, **сейчас думаю — невозможно**.*

Любая речь, разговорная или литературная, требует правильной постановки знаков препинания.

Comment: Хотелось бы дообсудить вообще-то...

Comment: Сейчас думаю,что невозможно — в

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Что ты хотел *дообсудить*, Артём? Видишь, простенький ответик (без примеров, разборов и рассмотрения другой пунктуации) уже ж одобрен.

Comment: Как одобрен, Рим? Это про какой ответ речь?

Comment: Здесь два разных смысла может быть, но об этом что-то никто не говорит.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Э-э... Чегой-то я, наверно, не понимаю, Артём. Я предполагала, что *дообсудить* надо мой (вот этот) ответ. А ты о чём?

Comment: Я про свой чешский вопрос.)) Так и не понял, кстати, что одобрено.

Comment: Да я про одобрение ответа Максима... Ночь уже... Пусть будет добрая! Оставим фарара на завтра?

Comment: А-а, ясно)) Хорошо, жду от тебя, что что-то скажешь сегодня. :)